# How can I run an .app as a desktop background/fake it?

Tags: macos, desktop

I'm using OSX 10.8.2 and I've been playing around with desktop background .plist files trying to run an app (specifically launchpad.app) on the desktop (replacing the usual background image) - it's proving tricky.

This would be a nice mod for the app you use most, as fullscreen apps find across-the-board support in Mountain Lion.